# Too many compound paths in illustrator.. need to merge and delete from an object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design

Hello everyone I had been trying to cut out many paths from a single layer in Illustrator. I was trying to convert an anchor point so I could move it but apparently I have ran into a problem.. My image that was previously cut out from a white circle disappeared.

I am transferring from photoshop but never had this problem before. I have many paths that are overlapped since I was trying to cut them all out from one layer.

Can I get any help on this? I can't seem to merge all the paths or compound shapes.. but everything that is within a path I want to delete from this white circle.

The layer that the paths are on is empty by the way

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Move the circle **below** the other art. (optional but will help this make more sense)
- Change the fill color of the circle to anything different than the other artwork (You can change it back later)
- Select the circle and other art
- Click the **Merge** button on the **Pathfinder Panel**
- Choose `Object > Ungroup` from the menu (optional but often helpful)
- Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) and click part of the circle.
- Choose `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke` from the menu
- Choose `Object > Lock` from the menu
- Still using the **Direct Selection Tool**, click-drag a selection to encompass everything.
- Hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key **twice**
- Choose `Object > Unlock All` from the menu
- Change the fill color back to white

This *should* work. To assist any further I'd need access to the actual file.

Comment: Scott I'm still having trouble with this. I have tried to merge the shapes in the pathfinder panel but it doesnt do anything. Only one of my paths is filled in with color, in fact I dont want any filled in.. I want to use all of the paths to delete from the circle. For some reason when I was trying to convert an anchor it just made my compound shape disappear. Even undo wouldn't bring it back.

Comment: A posted, I cant' really help further without access to the file. What I've posted here should work. If it fails, there's something about the file you aren't explaining or aren't aware of. Note, for pathfinder to work things need to have a fill - which can be removed later.

Comment: Can I upload the file to this post? I'm a newbie to illustrator so when I was making the compound shapes I would create new layer after new layer and make a compound shape one at a time each one using a different path to cut out the lines.

Comment: You can't upload files here. You'd have to host the file somewhere else, like dropbox or some other file sharing service.

Comment: Here is the file. https://www.mediafire.com/?r5wau1m9ybe036f     For some reason the pathfinder will work in cutting out from the circle but only 1 path which I cannot choose. The same path will fill while all of the other paths stay selected but nothing happens. Perhaps you can check it out and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: File is a mess with compound shapes within compound shapes within compound shapes. So much so that it's actually restricting further editing. **Manually** drag ever `<path>` element out of the compound shapes in the **Layers Panel**. When they are all [moved out of compound shapes as seen here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/z0fHE.jpg).... things look exactly as they are supposed to after my answer.

Comment: You've shot yourself in the foot my making simple art way, way, way too complex in construction.

Comment: I have noticed this.. I think I am just way too used to photoshop because when deleting paths from an image it wouldn't create an entire new shape. What is the easiest way to stay away from a problem like this? I see that you just have one compound shape with all the paths under it.. I'm guessing this is how to keep the file structure when creating compound shapes.